# Laravel Open AI API

Tags: php, laravel, api, chatgpt-api

Всем привет! Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно в поле  "content" прописать несколько промптов?
Например , чтобы в html было пару текстовых полей , которые в итоге собирают все сообщения в 1 единый запрос

> Надеюсь понятно объяснил)

```
public function messeges(Request $request)
{
    $Prompt = $request->input('prompt');
    return $this->askToChatGPT($Prompt);
}

private function askToChatGPT($Prompt) 
{
    $messages = [
        [
            "role" => "user",
            "content" => $Prompt
        ]
    ];

    $response = Http::withoutVerifying()
        ->withHeaders([
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . config('openai.api_key'),
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        ])->post('https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions', [
            "model" => "gpt-3.5-turbo",
            "messages" => $messages,
            "max_tokens" => 1000
        ]);

    return $response->json()['choices'][0]['message']['content'];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private function askToChatGPT($prompts) 
{
    $messages = [];

    // Добавляем каждый промпт как отдельное сообщение
    foreach ($prompts as $prompt) {
        $messages[] = [
            "role" => "user",
            "content" => $prompt
        ];
    }

    $response = Http::withoutVerifying()
        ->withHeaders([
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . config('openai.api_key'),
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        ])->post('https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions', [
            "model" => "gpt-3.5-turbo",
            "messages" => $messages,
            "max_tokens" => 1000
        ]);

    return $response->json()['choices'][0]['message']['content'];
}

public function messeges(Request $request)
{
    $prompts = $request->input('prompts'); // Массив промптов
    return $this->askToChatGPT($prompts);
}
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, попытался как-то с вашим кодом поработать , но  у меня постоянно ошибки , можете пожалуйста прислать пример с 2 промтами.Например чтобы всегда в начале отправленного messages было написано "Кратко" или что-то другое